# Doxygen is Slow

Tags: multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, doxygen

Doxygen takes about 12 hours to run on our code base. This is primarily because there is a lot of code to process (~1.5M lines). However, it's very quickly approaching the point at which we can't do nightly documentation updates because they take too long. We've already had to reduce the graph depth to get it down to 12 hours.

I've tried the standard approaches, but I really do need high quality output, and this includes graphs and SEARCH_INCLUDES. I have a fairly good machine to run Doxygen on, but Doxygen doesn't take advantage of its many cores. (It pegs a single CPU on the build server, but is only 4% of the available system.) Having a multithreaded Dot build is handy, though that's only half or so of the build time.

Are there any techniques I can use to run doxygen via multiple processes and manually shard the task? I've seen some talk about creating tag files, but I don't understand enough about them to know if they'd do what I want. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
doxygen Doxyfile-folder1
doxygen Doxyfile-folder2
doxygen Doxyfile-folder3
doxygen Doxyfile-folder4
doxygen-join output/folder1/html output/folder2/html output/folder3/html output/folder4/html
```

Of course, I'm just making stuff up, but that's an idea of what I'm looking for. Also, I'd use a lot more than 4 processes.

Comment: Does the server have enough RAM to keep the entire codebase cached and run doxygen without swapping?

Comment: More RAM and/or faster hard drive. Pick up an 80 GB SSD and put your code on that. Software that is IO intensive will benefit tremendously from a modern solid state hard drive.

Comment: Well, its currently sitting on a raid 10 array of 10k drives, so it shouldn't be that slow...

Comment: Late to the party but I have observed that doxygen 1.9 is slow on windows versus under WSL (20 minutes vs 3minutes). I don't know what the OS was here.

Answer (score 61):

Tag files are typically the way to go if

1. you have a number of logically coherent source files (let's call them components) and
2. you know the dependencies between the components, e.g. component A uses component B and C, and component B only uses C, and
3. It is ok (or even preferred) that the index files (e.g. the list of a files/classes/functions) are limited to a single component.
4. you are interested in HTML output.

A tag file is basically just a structured list of symbols with links to the location in the documentation. Tag files allow doxygen to make links from the documentation of one component to that of another.

It is a 2 step process:

1. First you run doxygen on each component to generate the tag file for that component. You can do this by disabling all output and use GENERATE_TAGFILE. So for component A, a Doxyfile.tagonly would have the following settings:

   ```
   GENERATE_HTML         = NO
   GENERATE_LATEX        = NO
   GENERATE_RTF          = NO
   GENERATE_MAN          = NO
   GENERATE_TAGFILE      = compA.tag
   ```

   You'll notice that running doxygen this way is *very* fast.
2. The second step is to generate the actual documentation. For component A you need a Doxyfile which includes the tag files of the components B and C since we determined A depends on these components.

   ```
   GENERATE_HTML         = YES
   GENERATE_LATEX        = NO
   GENERATE_RTF          = NO
   GENERATE_MAN          = NO
   TAGFILES              = path/to/compB/compB.tag=path/to/compB/htmldocs \
                           path/to/compC/compC.tag=path/to/compC/htmldocs
   ```

Using this approach I have been able to generate documentation for 20M+ lines of code distributed over 1500+ components in under 3 hours on a standard desktop PC (Core i5 with 8Gb RAM and Linux 64bit), including source browsing, full call graphs, and UML-style diagrams of all data structures. Note that the first step only took 10 minutes.

To accomplish this I made a script to generate the Doxyfile's for each component based on the list of components and their direct dependencies. In the first step I run 8 instances of doxygen in parallel (using http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/). In the second step I run 4 instances of doxygen in parallel.

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html for more info about tag files.

Comment: I'm not sure what it was before, but with Doxygen 1.8.2 I need to set `GENERATE_HTML=YES` when generating the tag file (the "master" build doesn't generate HTML documentation for the linked projects).

Comment: @doxygen - In Doxygen documentation, tag files are introduced in "Linking to external documentation" (http://www.doxygen.org/external.html). While that seems to be the initial purpose, tag files can be used otherwise too, e.g. multiple related (internal) projects, as per above answer. If so, it will help if the documentation is accordingly updated, for people looking to better organize and/or optimize their documentation.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "script to generate the Doxyfile's for each component based on the list of components and their direct dependencies"?

Comment: Does someone know if this works for the dot diagrams as well? I wasn't able to make it work.