# Merge Doxygen outputs (XML, QCH or man) of multiple modules in one single file

Tags: doxygen

### Setting

I'm writing scripts to generate documentation for a very modular project. I need to be able to generate the qch/man/xml documentation for each module and for the whole project.

What I'm currently doing is

1. Generate tags file
2. Generate qch, xml,...for each single module.
3. Generate again  for the whole project

### What I'm looking for

I would like to be able to do 1, 2 and then merge the results of 2 to get 2, without having to parse again the whole thing. Is it somehow possible?

In [1] and [2] they do not need to get the individual modules, they just parse them separately to gain time. It's useful, but not enough for me.

I'm ok with having some scripting hacks if needed, but until now I did not find anything working.

### Things I read

[1] [Doxygen is Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247189/doxygen-is-slow)

[2] [Merging doxygen modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570069/merging-doxygen-modules)