# doxygen create a top level project that indexes / links to sub projects

Tags: linux, doxygen

I have read [this](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-Projects-Languages-and-Shared-Config-Files-td3149.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570069/merging-doxygen-modules) but I still can't figure out how to do this.

So I have here is a fictional example (just to keep it small/simple):

```
top_level/
    |
    |--- proj1/
    |      |--- html/
    |
    |--- proj2/
    |      |--- html/
```

So here both proj1 and proj2 have generated html-style doxygen output into the sub-folders html/ - such that each of these contains an `index.html`

All I really want to do now is create a top-level doxygen page which will live in `top_level/html/` perhaps also named index.html that points to the two sub-projects.

Is that possible? I am really looking for a concrete example.

I had a little go with tagfiles. I was able to generate tag files for each subproject (by setting `GENERATE_TAGFILE=html/doxy.tag`.
I also add this into the top_level project: `TAGFILES=proj1/html/doxy.tag`

But I still just got an empty top_level page :(

Comment: With tag files it is possible to refer to "elements" for another project. So In your top_level part you could have a description of the sub packages and refer to them.

Comment: @albert thanks for that. As I mentioned at the end, I gave that a go, but it did not seem to work. Is there a good concrete example of how to do this?

Comment: Did you also try: `TAGFILES=proj1/html/doxy.tag:../../proj1/html` ? A large example (though it is from a real life project where there has been a lot of time invested to get it right) is at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/packages.html here is an overview (the mentioned page) and from there one can go to the subpackages.

Comment: @albert It did not work, I don't understand what the second part of the TAGFILES is after the semi-colon. What is that about? I tried every combiniation of relative paths, it just says that it now cant find this file `proj1/html/doxy.tag:../../proj1/html`.  The link you sent is a generated doxygen fileset. I really need to look at how they are created (i.e. what doxygen config is used).   My tag (as it was) is being read ok - no error - but I get no links to it in the documentation. Do I need to reference it in a comment? - thanks for your support

Comment: Sorry should have been an `=` sign (see doxygen documentation, number of `..` might also be incorrect I'm doingit by head). The file CGAL code, documentation parts etc. is in the CGAL repository on github. As said the CGAL structure is quite complicated with CMake etc.

Comment: @albert ehh...lol, I tried again a few more times, it did not error no matter what path I used (with `=`) but...  I never saw any output in my project. So I gave up and just found a way to generate a custom page with normal html-style links - much easier :)   thanks for your support though : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I kind of gave up on the tags.

In my top level project I created a `doxygen.md` file. I added this to the `INPUTS` Doxyfile tag.

Inside that file it looks like:

```
@mainpage

 .... some text ...

## Sub Modules
* <a href="../proj1/html/index.html>proj1</a>
* <a href="../proj2/html/index.html>proj1</a>
```

That is so much more simple that messing around with tags - and it does not need the sub folders to generate tags - I gave up on that idea! :)