# Doxygen optimization

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am trying to figure out how I can optimize Doxygen to run on my project in a reasonable amount of time. I have tried to use Tag files and divided my project up into subprojects so that I can parallelize/distribute the load of a Doxygen run. However, it appears that this feature is solely intended for linking to external documentation and not for joining projects in the way that I would like to.

I have used the ALLEXTERNALS tag to have my subproject class included in my main project however they are all tagged [external] and they only show up in the class list tab and not the class index or class hierarchy tab.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can parallelize/distribute Doxygen or, if not that, does anyone have any optimization tips?

Comment: How big is your project? My project has about 50,000 lines and doxygen runs in under a minute which I find acceptable.

Comment: One thing that can make a huge difference is what graphs you generate. If you don't want include graphs or class relationship graphs you can turn all of them off.

Comment: My project is around a couple of million lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247993/784672

Tag files can be used to link projects together, but they have their limitations in terms of integration (if the result would be the same there would be no performance advantage). 
That said: if you think entries are missing from the index then please file a bug report in the bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you, I did see that posting however tags do not work in the way I thought that they would. They are very much for external libs. When breaking up your project into subprojects to optimize a Doxygen run they make navigation of the UI counter intuitive. For instance if you have modules defined then clicking on a module will send the user to the main page of that subproject without a link back to your main project. Also, at the top level you cannot see the class indices for subprojects. This makes tags for dividing a single project not a viable option if you want a unified view