# Documenting huge code

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document a huge C++-project. Due to hardware limitations I am not able to document the entire code at once. Hence I divided my code into two modules (A and B), and am using the `TAGFILES` option to document dependencies.

**For A**

```
GENERATE_TAGFILE = A_tags
TAGFILES =  ""
```

**For B**

```
GENERATE_TAGFILE = B_tags
TAGFILES = "A_tags = doxygenated_A/html"
```

However, A and B depend on each other, but using the above configuration I am unable to solve A’s dependency on B.

Can you please suggest how to solve A’s dependency on B?

Comment: Do you mean "huge" instead of "hugh"?

Comment: what hardware limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two runs. One run that generates the tag files only for all projects (and no output) and a second run to generate the actual output using the tag files.

See also my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247993/784672 for more details.

Comment: I tried generating the documents using this method, i.e used 2 runs.


But I see that when I refer to module B code from module A I get webpage not found. 


[file:///C:/Users/jaia/Desktop/Doxygenating_code/MODULE_A/html/search/MODULE_B/h‌​tml/d3/d2d/BaseEnvelopDriver_8cpp.xhtml]


As seen above both Module A and B are found but links are not created correctly 


Can you please suggest a remedy.

Comment: The assignment after the A_tags in TAGFILES, should be the relative path to get from project B's html output directory to projects A's html output directory, i.e. typically A_tags=../../doxygenated_A/html"