# Doxygen:- Error in links generated between 2 modules

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document a huge C++-project. Due to hardware limitations I am not able to document the entire code at once.

Hence I divided my code into two modules (A and B), and am using the TAGFILES option to document dependencies.

**For A**

GENERATE_TAGFILE = A_tags

TAGFILES = ""

**For B**

GENERATE_TAGFILE = B_tags

TAGFILES = "A_tags = doxygenated_A/html"

I tried generating the documents using this method, i.e used 2 runs, 1st for generating Tags only and 2nd for generating actual document.

But I see that when I refer to module A code from module B I get webpage not found Error. AS the brwser trys to find the following link :-

[file:///C:/Users/jaia/Desktop/Doxygenating_code/**MODULE_A**/html/search/**MODULE_B**/h‌​‌​tml/d3/d2d/BaseEnvelopDriver_8cpp.xhtml]

As seen above as per doxygen documentation Module B is in C:/Users/jaia/Desktop/Doxygenating_code/Module_A/html/search but actually Module B is in folder C:/Users/jaia/Desktop/Doxygenating_code

i.e My Folder Structure is

Doxygenating_code

```
|- Module A

|- Module B
```

Hence as seen above the links are not created properly, is there anyway to correct this?

Can you please assist me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment after the A_tags in TAGFILES, should be the relative path to get from project B's html output directory to projects A's html output directory, i.e. typically A_tags=../../doxygenated_A/html

For More details please refer doxygen's answer in

[Documenting huge code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049014/documenting-huge-code)