# Create a common Doxygen index.html from many index.html

Tags: doxygen, ros

I have a doc folder with many folders inside. Each folder contains a doc.tag file (generated from Doxygen) and html folder with the Doxygen output. Example:

```
doc
|- Proj1
     |- doc.tag
     |- html
         |- index.html
         |- other doxygen html output
|- Proj2
     |- doc.tag
     |- html
         |- index.html
         |- other doxygen html output
| and so on
```

I want to know if there is any way of creating a common Doxygen `index.html` from all the `index.html` files in the folders. It would be nice if the Doxygen search could work through all of them.

Details: each folder is a ROS package and the documentation is generated from a CMake macro (https://github.com/ethz-asl/doxygen_catkin) used in every package's CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution at the end was not really straightforward. However, it is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247189/doxygen-is-slow/8247993#8247993).

The CMake macro mentioned was modified to save a file in each folder with the full path to the tag file of that specific package.

Then, a custom CMake target was created which depends on all the other targets, so that we ensure it builds the last. A postbuild command was included, running a python script which parses all the files created with path from tag files and configured a Doxyfile including the path to these tag files. And then, ran doxygen in this Doxyfile.